# Failed to save struct field in Delta Table

Tags: pyspark, hive, nested, delta-lake

I tried to save the table to Delta using SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS simple_table (
`id` string,
`amount` decimal(20,4), 
`description` struct<`key` string>)
USING DELTA
PARTITIONED BY (dt)
LOCATION '/path_to_dir';
```

but I got error `mismatched input '<' expecting {')', ',', 'CONSTRAINT'}`

so, what is the right way to save struct/nested field?

Comment: what version of the Spark & Delta?

Comment: Spark 3.1 Delta 1.0 @AlexOtt, I post the answer bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw Databricks documentation about complex datatype [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-hiveformat.html#:%7E:text=--Use%20complex%20datatype)
and it's actually simple, just pust `:` in the struct field

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS simple_table (
`id` string,
`amount` decimal(20,4), 
`description` struct<`key`:string>)
USING DELTA
PARTITIONED BY (dt)
LOCATION '/path_to_dir';
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need backticks because identifiers which you are using are not reserved words. Struct in DDL looks like this: `struct<key: string>`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS simple_table (
id string,
amount decimal(20,4), 
description struct<key: string>
)
USING DELTA
PARTITIONED BY (dt)
LOCATION '/path_to_dir';
```

Comment: already tried this, and still failed